# What web sites are available that contain good examples of user interface design?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

There must be many online resources for good user interface design principles. I'd like to see an easily-browsed list, perhaps categorized by desktop vs. on-line (or maybe not; that might be too limiting).

Any examples out there?

**The List (so far)**
[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/)
[Designing Web Interfaces](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/)
[Jakob Nielsen's useit.com](http://www.useit.com)
[Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/)
[Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/)
[Usability Post](http://www.usabilitypost.com/)
[Yahoo Design Pattern Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/)
[Designing Web Interfaces](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/)

also, [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/) is pretty good.

as is [Usability Post](http://www.usabilitypost.com/)

Comment: Also, This article collects four great sources, I've used UI Patterns personally: [UX Movement 4 Best Design Pattern Libraries][1]


  [1]: http://uxmovement.com/resources/4-best-design-pattern-libraries/

Answer (score 4):

I honestly think that StackOverflow really has a well thought out UI.  Access to most everything is intuitive and efficient.

I've already changed some of my own interfaces based on things I have seen here.

Comment: I agree, StackOverflow UI is very nice to use.

Comment: Yet another example that proves good design doesn't mean *pretty* design.

Answer (score 3):

[Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/) by Infragistics has a pretty good selection.

Answer (score 2):

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) provide articles about design and also how to make them standards compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Don't miss Jakob Nielsen's [useit.com](http://www.useit.com) website.

Comment: Oddly enough, Jakob's site is one of the most un-navigable sites around today.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for "design patterns," common ways we present and perform interactions, such as those discussed in Jenifer Tidwell's book, *Designing Interfaces*.  Her book's site links to her original pattern library, Common Ground, as well, but the book is a good one to own.

Yahoo! has a [Design Pattern Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/), focused on web design patterns, and Quince was mentioned in a previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

http://designingwebinterfaces.com/, the accompanying website to the homonym book has some good patterns.